# Migrating from Eclipse to AndroidStudio: Attribute has already been defined

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, eclipse-adt

I'm currently trying to migrate my android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Building the projects fails with following errors:

> :app:processDebugResources
>
> .../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
>
> Error:(204) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
>
> Error:(233) Attribute "color" has already been defined

Here is the line 204 from valuex.xml

```
    <declare-styleable name="MyView"><attr format="dimension" name="off"/><attr format="integer" name="host_mode"/><attr format="dimension" name="h_textSize"/><attr format="dimension" name="header_textSize"/><attr format="dimension" name="h_rx"/><attr format="dimension" name="h_ry"/><attr format="dimension" name="divider_height"/><attr format="color" name="divider"/><attr format="dimension" name="chat_divider_height"/><attr format="color" name="chat_divider"/><attr format="color" name="background_color"/><attr format="boolean" name="use_name"/></declare-styleable>
```

module gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/alljoyn.jar')
compile files('libs/peergroupmanager.jar')
}
```

Does anyone know where's the problem?

UPDATE:
this is the modul's complete gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/alljoyn.jar')
    compile files('libs/peergroupmanager.jar')
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I changed my gradle file according to xhamr. I get a different error message now:

> :app:processDebugResources
>
> ../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
>
> Error:(204) Attribute "divider" already defined with incompatible
>
> format. Error:(182) Original attribute defined here.

Line 182:

```
    <declare-styleable name="ActionBar"><attr name="navigationMode"><enum name="normal" value="0"/><enum name="listMode" value="1"/><enum name="tabMode" value="2"/></attr><attr name="displayOptions"><flag name="none" value="0"/><flag name="useLogo" value="0x1"/><flag name="showHome" value="0x2"/><flag name="homeAsUp" value="0x4"/><flag name="showTitle" value="0x8"/><flag name="showCustom" value="0x10"/><flag name="disableHome" value="0x20"/></attr><attr name="title"/><attr format="string" name="subtitle"/><attr format="reference" name="titleTextStyle"/><attr format="reference" name="subtitleTextStyle"/><attr format="reference" name="icon"/><attr format="reference" name="logo"/><attr format="reference" name="divider"/><attr format="reference" name="background"/><attr format="reference|color" name="backgroundStacked"/><attr format="reference|color" name="backgroundSplit"/><attr format="reference" name="customNavigationLayout"/><attr name="height"/><attr format="reference" name="homeLayout"/><attr format="reference" name="progressBarStyle"/><attr format="reference" name="indeterminateProgressStyle"/><attr format="dimension" name="progressBarPadding"/><attr name="homeAsUpIndicator"/><attr format="dimension" name="itemPadding"/><attr format="boolean" name="hideOnContentScroll"/><attr format="dimension" name="contentInsetStart"/><attr format="dimension" name="contentInsetEnd"/><attr format="dimension" name="contentInsetLeft"/><attr format="dimension" name="contentInsetRight"/><attr format="dimension" name="elevation"/><attr format="reference" name="popupTheme"/></declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Can you share complete build.gradle it nmight be helpful to understand the issue

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're targeting SDK 24 and using compact library v24 as well, try setting `compileSdkVersion 24` as

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 24
    ...
}
```

*make sure you have the latest build tool from SDK Manager*

**EDIT**:

After the update the problem isn't in your dependencies is on your `declare-styleable`. android define an attribute named `divider` which collide with yours, just change the name of your `divider` attribute:

```
<attr format="color" name="divider_color"/>
```

Comment: I get a different error message now. Please take a look at my update

Comment: But I don't have this issue in eclipse. So how can something be wrong with my code then?

Comment: The new issue is because of changes in dependencies and build tool, the same attr is defined by android with a format different than yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update all tools and SDK support libraries. to do this go to your Android Studio and open SDK manager and install updates.
2. Then restart your Android Studio
3. Check your buil.gradle and update below lines of code as per latest version

   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

   targetSdkVersion 24

   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
4. Sync the project
5. Rebuild